# Using jinja2 macro from filter using jingo

Tags: django, macros, jinja2

I'm developing a Django app using jinja2 through jingo. I have a macro defined in `templates/macros.html` and I need to call it from a filter defined in `helpers.py` because there is some kind of python-logic involved in the parameters I have to pass it. Is there any way to do so?

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

in `templates/macros.html`:

```
{% macro render_link(obj) -}
    <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url() }}">{{ obj }}</a>
-%}
```

in `helpers.py`:

```
@register.filter
def as_link(obj_or_list):
    if hasattr(obj_or_list, '__iter__'):
        for obj in obj_or_list:
            # call `render_link(obj)` here and concat results somehow
    else:
        # call `render_link(obj_or_list)` here
```

whenever I need it, in my templates:

```
{{ an_object|as_link }}
```

I need to use the filter here because I need to do some stuff with the parameters before passing them to the macro. I know I could write the logic in the macro itself, but I would need to add some methods to the jinja2 environment (such as `hasattr` in the example) and this is not feasible when the logic involved is too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I came out with a solution. Macros are defined in templates, so first of all I needed to load it. Reading the source code I found out how to get the macro function from a template instance, so here's the correct way to do so:

```
@register.filter()
def as_link(obj_or_list):
    from jingo import env

    template = env.get_template('macros.html')
    render_link = template.module.render_link

    if hasattr(obj_or_list, '__iter__'):
        return ''.join((render_link(obj) for obj in obj_or_list))
    return render_link(obj_or_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this works, but maybe the macro is registered as a global function. Macros and Global Python functions can be called in the same way from a template.

If your macro was registered, you can :

```
env.globals['render_link'](obj)
```

If this does now work, you can always include the macro code as Python code in your filter. In your filter you have all the Python power.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. `env` contains only registered filters and functions, but no macros. I investigated and came out with a solution, though